# SP2013 - Migrate SQL from all in one server to separate servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql, standard

I have a SharePoint implementation that was set up (not by me) with everything on one VM, SharePoint and SQL. We now have a requirement to move SQL to a separate server to increase performance and my Google searches are coming up blank.

Does anyone know if its possible to (and if so, the procedure to do so) migrate SQL to a different (new) server and leave the SharePoint VM running just SharePoint?

Current setup:

SP Server - Running SharePoint 2013 as WFE, Application, Search and also holds SQL for SharePoint.

I've checked and the farm isn't in standalone mode.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it farm mode? What version of sql u are using?

Comment: Yes, it's in farm mode. I checked in the registry and confirmed it wasn't in standalone mode. Version of SQL is SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can move them to different SQL server. Please follow the steps below.

1. Prepare the New SQL Server( setting up permission, MAx degree settings etc)
2. Mark the DB read-Only on Source Server, take the Backup
3. Restore the Backup on new SQL server and attach to SQL, Set the Permissions on them
4. Shut down Sharepoint( stopping IIS, timer Service, other services), this is to make sure no active connection to SQL from SharePoint.
5. Create An alias on the SharePoint Server which point to new Sql Server
6. start the SharePoint
7. test it.

Please read [this technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx) for more in detail steps.